# RSS + Foreign characters -> Validation error

Tags: utf-8, rss

I have an RSS feed and one of the links has an 'ó' in it which causes validation issue. Is it not possible to include these characters in the URI? Is it bad practice to have a character like this in the URI anyway?

Feed us UTF-8.

Comment: Can we see the feed, please, or at least enough of an extract of it to know where this character is?

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters are legal in URI's. Now you can also use them in domain names. So you have error in your validation mechanism.